# Как сделать ActionBar полу круглый

Tags: android, actionbar

Всем привет , помогите сделать ActionBar полу круглым типа такова как пример при нажатии на Button тени , вот хочу сделать чтобы был не просто цвет ActionBar а чтобы были тона

Comment: Вам нужен полукруглый `ActionBar`? Чтоб при касании цвет менялся или что?

Comment: Нет чтобы цвет не менялся а просто было 2 тона 1 темно синий 2 тон светло синий и чтобы было так два цвета были единые

Comment: Типа как градиент

Comment: ActionBar цвета полукруглых тонов.

Comment: ActionBar тона теней полу_круглого цвета.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте в папке `res/drawable` файл с кодом

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <gradient 
     android:startColor="#000"  <!-- верхний цвет -->
     android:endColor="#fff" <!-- нижний цвет -->
     android:angle="90"
  />
 </shape>
```

Создайте стиль для `ActionBar` в `res/values/styles.xml`

```
 <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_bg</item>
 </style>
```

И присвойте его в главной теме активности/приложения

```
 <style name="AppThemeBase" parent="Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
 </style>
```

**P.S.**

Градиенты не в моде, `ActionBar` не в моде, переходите на `Toolbar` и изучите концепцию `Material Design`

Comment: Спасибо большое